# Can we enforce a P3 Penrose tiling using unmarked rhombi with a small set of local matching rules?

Tags: tiling

Suppose I've got some rhombi that I want my friend to construct a P3 Penrose tiling out of:

[image]

However, the edge markings on my tiles have worn off, so I need to give my friend instructions about how to place unmarked tiles edge-to-edge such that they are constrained to only produce valid Penrose tilings from the set.

One local condition that holds of a Penrose tiling is that no rhombus shares an edge with a congruent rhombus in the same orientation - we could try giving my friend this rule to follow. However, that's not enough, because they could still screw up and make something like this:

[image]

Is there a small number of additional "simple" rules we can impose that will constrain the possible tilings nicely? Of course something like "all tile arrangements within radius 10 of a vertex must be one of the following forms" should suffice, but I'm curious if there's a compact characterization of Penrose tilings that enforces the necessary matching rules without relying on correspondences between distant tiles or lots of casework. Apologies for the subjectivity of this question, but I hope it's clear what I'm gesturing at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing some code to explore this more, I've found a characterization that I like.

In any tiling of the plane by rhombi, we can cross from an edge to the parallel edge on the opposite side of a face, and repeat this procedure to get a "ladder" of parallel edges, which also gives us a ribbon of rhombs joined at opposite edges. An example of this phenomenon:

[image]

In order to enforce that our tiling be a Penrose tiling, it suffices to enforce the following two rules:

- For a given type of rhomb (thick or thin), the directions they point in as you go along a ladder should alternate. So if a vertical ribbon has a thin rhomb pointing left, the next thin rhomb on that ladder should point right.
- No vertex should have all four angles ($\frac\pi5, \frac{2\pi}5, \frac{3\pi}5, \frac{4\pi}5$) meet.

This amounts to forbidding the following ten configurations (in fact the first rule forbids infinitely many, but the below suffice to force the tiling to obey the matching rules):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.08239.pdf) by Lutfalla and Fernique provided one possible answer to this question. The restrictions imposed by the possible vertex figures do not suffice, as demonstrated in this counterexample:

[image]

But if we require the tiles touching every edge emanating from a given vertex to come from a valid Penrose tiling, i.e. one of the following 15 configurations:

[image]

then it is forced to be a valid Penrose tiling.

This is not that compactly describable, though, so I'm not accepting this self-answer yet in hopes that a better classification of unmarked Penrose tilings is posted.

---

Edit 2023-05-14: Theorem 6.1 of M. Seneschal's *Quasicrystals and Geometry* states that any tiling whose vertex figures ("stars") are one of the seven allowable configurations *and* such that no two stars that share a rhomb are related by a half-turn about the center of that rhomb is a Penrose tiling. (Note that this second condition fails to obtain in the above counterexample - there are two kinds of vertices with the aforementioned 180 degree symmetry.)